# Craft 3 RegEx problem

Tags: regex

I am trying to change all rgb colours in a bit of text/content. I have the RegEx working here in php using preg_replace:

```
preg_replace("/#[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}|rgb\((?:\s*\d+\s*,){2}\s*[\d]+\)|rgba\((\s*\d+\s*,){3}[\d\.]+\)|hsl\(\s*\d+\s*(\s*\,\s*\d+\%){2}\)|hsla\(\s*\d+(\s*,\s*\d+\s*\%){2}\s*\,\s*[\d\.]+\)/", "*****", $input_lines);
```

https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/oc2

But cannot seem to get it working in craft template code am trying is like this:

```
{% set svg_image = '
#ffffff
#ffffffasdf
asdf#ffffff
rgba(170,221,255,0.59)
rgba(170,221,255,0.59)asdf
rgb(0, 0, 0)
rgb(33, 44,66)
rgb(0,0,0)asdf
rgba(170,221,255,0.59dsaf)
' %} 

{% set svg_image_output = svg_image|replace({ '/#[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}|rgb\\((?:\\s*\\d+\\s*,){2}\\s*[\\d]+\\)|rgba\\((\\s*\\d+\\s*,){3}[\\d\\.]+\\)|hsl\\(\\s*\\d+\\s*(\\s*\\,\\s*\\d+\\%){2}\\)|hsla\\(\\s*\\d+(\\s*,\\s*\\d+\\s*\\%){2}\\s*\\,\\s*[\\d\\.]+\\)/': '****' }) %}
{{ svg_image_output | raw }}
```

I have:
 - added double-escaped '\' as the docs suggest in v2
 - started with / and ended with /

Seems in the docs that if this is done it works like preg_replace.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close!

Just don't use the Twig hash/array syntax when using the `|replace` filter if you want Craft to process it as regex.  This should do what you're looking for:

```
{% set svg_image_output = svg_image|replace('/#[a-zA-Z0-9]{6}|rgb\\((?:\\s*\\d+\\s*,){2}\\s*[\\d]+\\)|rgba\\((\\s*\\d+\\s*,){3}[\\d\\.]+\\)|hsl\\(\\s*\\d+\\s*(\\s*\\,\\s*\\d+\\%){2}\\)|hsla\\(\\s*\\d+(\\s*,\\s*\\d+\\s*\\%){2}\\s*\\,\\s*[\\d\\.]+\\)/', '****') %}
```